# User has shared access to his personal account in Office365 via OAuth2. How to revoke shared access programmatically?

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory, office365api, revokeobjecturl

I can manage sharing access by user to his personal [Office365 account via OAuth2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow). This article does not contain information how to revoke the access. I believe there is should be REST API to revoke shared access.

---

Can I have help or missed link to Office365 developers API where I could find correspond documentation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to revoke access token issued by azure ad , currently , Azure AD doesn’t support revoking the token . However, we can clear the token cache if you doesn’t want users to user the token. You could also read document [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) to specify the lifetime of a token issued by Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) .

Comment: @nan-yu-msft Do you want me configure token policy if I need recall one? Is it correct to configure lifetime policy if token already shared?
On same article page you could find `Until-revoked` in `Configurable token lifetime properties` table. It means someone cane revoke token | access but  I should fix tokens' lifetime, isn't it? Right now it sounds like hack for me. Could you please add more details (to change this conclusion)?

Comment: @nan-yu-msft `Azure AD doesn’t support revoking the token` - do you know some plans to support revoke token? Can I take a look shared development plan?

Comment: No , Access tokens cannot be revoked and are valid until their expiry , configure token lifetime could reduce risk

Comment: You could send a feedback in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory)